# Is there an equivalent to netscan?

Tags: networking, software-recommendation

I use netscan in windows to browse network shares on lan. I can see all the network shares at one place and open them by a mere click. Can I do same on ubuntu, is there any netscan for ubuntu which can exactly do the same

Answer (score 2):

Netscan (for windows) is a very handy tool for browsing lan. There is a similar application for linux too, named ---ShareScanner (netscan for linux). You can download it from:

http://sharescanner.net84.net

The site contains 32 and 64 bit debian and rpm packages for easy installation. It is actually a gui for smbclient.